# fade in png with transparency into an mp4 video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing, visual-effects

I am trying to overlay a png file with transparency into an mp4 video

the original video is 20sec and I want to overlay the transparent png from 00:10 to 00:20 of the original video, with the 00:10 - 00:14 to fade in.

```
     0s                                10s      14s                       20s
video |---------------------------------+--------+-------------------------|
png   | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . +========+-------------------------|
                                        |        |                         |
                    start png fade-in _/         |                         |
                                                 |                         |
                                end png fade-in _/                         |
                                                     end of .png overlay _/
```

I cannot create the png fadein effect.
I tried creating a transparent mov with

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i file.png -frames:v 300 -vf 'fade=in:0:120' \
           -pix_fmt rgba -vcodec png  output.mov
```

and joining the 2 files with

```
../ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i output.mov -filter_complex \
            "[0:v][1:v] overlay=170:150:enable='between(t,10,20)'" final.mp4
```

but the final video displays the mov in a flash without fading in.

Is there something I am missing?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create the overlay mov as a separate step.

First create the overlay **like a movie** in this way:

> -loop 1 -i watermark.png

Then use a fade filter to fade in for 4 seconds (that is 100 frames):

> fade=in:0:100

And then delay it by 10 seconds to start later in this way:

> setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB

Your command then becomes:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -loop 1 -i watermark.png -filter_complex \  
"[1:v]fade=in:0:100[v1]; [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];  \  
[v1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[v3];[v0][v3]overlay=eof_action=pass[out1]"  \  
-map [out1] <other parameters> overlaidoutput.mp4
```

The overlay will continue to the end. And of course you can use many fine-tuning parameters within the "**other parameters**" section.

**NOTE:** I used 100 frames for 4 seconds because I used PAL 25 fps. You can change that to 120 frames if you work in 30 fps.

---

If you need to end the overlay at a specific time point, you can also use the `enable` parameter:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -loop 1 -i watermark.png -filter_complex \  
"[1:v]fade=in:0:100[v1]; [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];  \  
[v1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[v3];  \  
[v0][v3]overlay=enable='between(t,10,12)':eof_action=pass[out1]"  \  
-map [out1] <other parameters> overlaidoutput.mp4
```

This ends the overlay at 12 seconds. **Make sure you are using ffmpeg ver 2 or above.**

Comment: Anyone knows why the audio of the input movie is lost in the output?

Comment: Looks like when I don't use eof_action pass, it has working audio, but encoding will run in an endless loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this [AviSynth](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Main_Page) script:

> LoadPlugin("AviSynth+/plugins/ffms2-2.23.1-msvc/x86/ffms2.dll")
> video = FFmpegSource2("video.mp4", atrack=1)
> vseg1 = video.Trim(0, 419)
> vseg2 = video.Trim(420, 599)
> iseg1 = ImageSource("file.png", end=119, fps=30)
> iseg2 = ImageSource("file.png", end=179, fps=30)
> clip1 = Dissolve(vseg1, iseg1, 120)
> clip2 = Overlay(vseg2, overlay=iseg2, x=170, y=150, mask=iseg2.ShowAlpha("RGB32"))
> clip1 + clip2

Then:

> ffmpeg.exe -i script.avs -c:v libx265 -pass 1 -c:a aac -f mp4 -n output.mp4

**Warning**: code is just a stub; **not tested**!